# Applying Bender's decomposition using CPLEX example

Tags: mathematical-optimization, cplex, decomposition

I want to implement bender's decomposition method using CPLEX example in my model. The function works but the results are not correct. I should mention that the objective value of my master problem at the beginning is zero, then the variables values are zero. In the attached file you can find my results. It seems only on time the master and sub problems are called. Could you please help me to realize the problem? How can I fix the problem?

[image]